# Error during creation of variable on Pandas - Wrong number of items passed

Tags: python, pandas, variables

I am receiving the error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1, and I am struggling to figure out where, and how I may begin addressing the problem.

I don't really understand the meaning of the error; which is making it difficult for me to troubleshoot. I have also included the block of code that is triggering the error in my Jupyter Notebook.

I have trouble to create a variable on dataframe according to many conditions.

I wish add a column with a binary variable 'Yes'/'No' according the answer at conditions.

My dataframe is build from CSV file with 11 columns.

I try this code :

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df['yes/no'] = np.where(df[(df['var_1'].isin(list)) & (df['var2'] >= '2000-01-01') & (df['var_2'] <= '2000-12-31') & (df['var_3'] >0) & (df['var_4'] =='OK')],'yes','No')
```

I think the problem come from the creation of variable because the code is correct without the `np.where` condition.

But when i want create a variable with those conditions and execute the code it display the error :

```
Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1
```

Do you know what it means that error and how to fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.where` returns an array of the size only of the number of matches it finds. If you want to add a column to a your df you need a series the same size, with `True` or `False` depending on the condition. For this just use a bare condition:

```
df['yes/no'] = 'No'
rows = (df['var_1'].isin(list)) & 
    (df['var2'] >= '2000-01-01') & 
    (df['var_2'] <= '2000-12-31') & 
    (df['var_3'] >0) & 
     (df['var_4'] =='OK')
df.loc[rows, 'yes/no'] = 'yes'
```

Comment: Thks a lot @josh Friendlander, it perfect